# Split Column to Date and Time

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to split a column that contains a combination of Date and Time into two columns, where date and time are separated.

Column C contains a combination of date and time, for example "2022-01-01 09:30:00".
This should be split into Date in Column D and Time in Column E, in the format "dd.mm.yyyy" and "hh:mm":
Column D with 01.01.2022
Column E with "09:30"

I need to compare with a different sheet, where they are in this format.

Although I managed to split Date and Time into two columns the Time format is wrong.

I found suggestions to use Int() to get the date, and then subtract to get the time, however my date seems to be string. I tried to format my column to a Date datatype by using the Cdate function, however this resulted in an error.

As I don't necessarily need the value to have this datatype, I thought I could work with the Left() and Right() function. This first gave a problem but by including a string in between, I am getting closer to what I want.

```vb
Dim iAircol As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim spacepos as Int

iAircol= Worksheets(ws).Cells.Find(What:="Airdate", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    spacepos = InStr(Cells(i, iAircol), " ")
    str1 = Left(Cells(i, iAircol).Value, spacepos)
    Cells(i, iAircol + 1) = str1
    str2 = Left(Right(Cells(i, iAircol).Value, Len(Cells(i, iAircol)) - spacepos), 6)
    Cells(i, iAircol + 2) = str2
Next i
```

Time value still is in "hh:mm:ss":
[image]

I give the cell the first 5 characters of the total time, so no idea why it ends up with all 8 characters again, and this should be a string now, but `Debug.Print` gives me the Type "Date" for the date, and a Double for the Time.

Comment: Dates are not strings but numbers. Same with time. You can change the format of the cells to match the one you want, but the number will remain the same.

Comment: I know that Dates are numbers, however the Dates in my file seem to be strings (I get them from an external source). When I check with TypeName it at least gives me strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateValue` and `TimeValue`, they are exactly for this:

```
Cells(i, iAircol + 1) = DateValue(Cells(i, iAircol))
Cells(i, iAircol + 2) = TimeValue(Cells(i, iAircol))
```

Then apply the **Format** you prefer to the two date and time columns, as these will hold true *DateTime* values, not text.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This saved my day, exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next function to split the string as you need:

```
Function splitDateTime(strTime As String) As Variant
   Dim d As Date, t As Date, arrD
   arrD = Split(Split(strTime, " ")(0), "-")
   
   d = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(0)), CLng(arrD(1)), CLng(arrD(2)))
   t = CDbl(CDate(Format(Split(strTime, " ")(1), "hh:mm")))
   splitDateTime = Array(d, t)
End Function
```

It can be tested like this:

```
Sub testSplitDateTime()
   Dim arr, ac As Range
   
   Set ac = ActiveCell 'in the active cell should be the string to be split/converted...
   arr = splitDateTime(ac.value)
   ac.Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "HH:mm"
   Range(ac.Offset(0, 1), ac.Offset(0, 2)).value = arr   
End Sub
```